# Weighted average of multiple points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let's say I have a triangle whose three corners are $$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3).$$ I have a weight assigned to each one as a percentage, so the first point might be $75\%$, the second $15\%$ and the third $10\%$.

How would I find the weighted centroid of this triangle?

If it helps, it's an equilateral triangle. I'm coding a visualization in JavaScript and I'm stuck on some of the math. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the formula

$$(w_1x_1+w_2x_2+w_3x_3, w_1y_1+w_2y_2+w_3y_3)$$
where $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are positive weights adding up to $1$.